# Golang render new template on button press

Tags: html, go, templates

I have a button which adds a player to the program, this is done in HTML. I would like this button to render a new partial template when the player is submitted. This is currently not happening even though the code is reaching this point. The jQuery is working fine and sending the correct data through, the code is just not rendering the new template. Any help would be great thanks.

Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type playerType struct {
    Fname string
    Lname string
    // Men are true and Women are false
    Gender bool
}

var players []playerType

var templates *template.Template

func handleFilePath() {
    http.Handle("/templates/", http.StripPrefix("/templates/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates"))))
    http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))

    //templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./templates/index.html", "./templates/displayPlayer.html"))

    templates = template.Must(template.New("").ParseGlob("./templates/*.html"))
}

func landingPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
        return
    }
}

func addPlayerHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    Fname := r.FormValue("fname")
    Lname := r.FormValue("lname")
    Gender := r.FormValue("gender")

    if addPlayer(Fname, Lname, Gender) {
        log.Printf("Player added: %v, %v, %v", Fname, Lname, Gender)
        err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "displayPlayer", players[0])
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func addPlayer(Fname string, Lname string, Gender string) bool {

    if Fname == "" || Lname == "" || Gender == "" {
        return false
    }

    var playerToBeAdded playerType

    // Set men to true and women to false
    if strings.ToLower(Gender) == "male" {
        playerToBeAdded = playerType{Fname, Lname, true}
    } else {
        playerToBeAdded = playerType{Fname, Lname, false}
    }

    players = append(players, playerToBeAdded)

    return true
}

func main() {
    handleFilePath()
    http.HandleFunc("/", landingPage)

    log.Println("Listening...")

    http.HandleFunc("/addPlayer", addPlayerHandler)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
}
```

HMTL Templates:
index.html:

```
{{ define "home" }}
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/home.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home - Match Maker</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="/assets/home.js"></script>

<!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="addPlayer">Add Player</button>

<button onclick="generateGames()">Generate Games</button>

</br>

{{ template "displayPlayer" .}}

</br>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/" method="post">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="/assets/be.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <label for="fname" style="align-content: center"><b>First Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="firstName" required>

            <label for="lname" style="align-content: center"><b>Last Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" name="lastName" required>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            Select Gender:
            </br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male
            </label>
            </br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1; text-align: center">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="modelButtons">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button id="subbtn" type="submit" class="modelButtons"
                    onclick="submitPlayer(firstName.value, lastName.value, gender.value)">Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

displayPlayer.html:

```
{{ define "displayPlayer" }}
<html lang="en">
<body>
{{ .Fname }}
</br>
{{ .Lname }}
</br>
{{ .Gender }}
</body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

Javascript:

home.js:

```
function submitPlayer(fname, lname, gender) {
    if (fname == "" || lname == "" || gender == "") {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPlayer',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            fname: fname,
            lname: lname,
            gender: gender,
        },
        success: (d) => {
            console.log("Player Added");
        },
        error: (d) => {
            console.log("An error occurred. Please try again");
        }
    });
}

function generateGames() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/createGames',
        method: 'post',
        success: (d) => {
            console.log("Generated Games");
        },
        error: (d) => {
            console.log("An error occurred. Please try again");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The HTML document won't update by itself. You have to do that in the success callback for the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks Peter, would you be able to show me/explain what should go in there. A location.reload(); did not work :(
Thanks :)

Comment: Add an element with an id where you want the contents to show up and put something like `$("#my-div").html(d)` in the success callback. You should remove the HTML skeleton from the template if you want to do this. If you want to replace the whole page, don't bother with ajax at all. Just submit a good old form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Moved **home.js** down at the end so js loads after html content are loaded to DOM.
- Added table with players id to add data returned by `addPlayers`
- removed `submitPlayer`
- added `onSubmit` to form so we can prevent page from reloading because as soon we submit form the page reloads causes to lose data returned by `addPlayer`

**index.html**

```html
{{ define "home" }}
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/home.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home - Match Maker</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="addPlayer">Add Player</button>

<button onclick="generateGames()">Generate Games</button>

</br>

{{ template "displayPlayer" .}}

</br>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <form class="modal-content animate" action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return onSubmit(event);">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            <img src="/assets/be.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <label for="fname" style="align-content: center"><b>First Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="firstName" required>

            <label for="lname" style="align-content: center"><b>Last Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Smith" name="lastName" required>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            Select Gender:
            </br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male
            </label>
            </br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1; text-align: center">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="modelButtons">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button id="subbtn" type="submit" class="modelButtons">Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
      <table id="players"></table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/assets/home.js"></script>
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

- Updated **displayPlayer.html** to table row format so we can add it to table.

**displayPlayer.html**

```
{{ define "displayPlayer" }}
<tr>
  <td>
    {{ .Fname }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ .Lname }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ .Gender }}
  </td>
{{ end }}
```

- function to send form data to `addPlayer` api

**home.js**

```js
var players = document.querySelector('#players');

function onSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  let form = evt.target;
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let fname = formData.get('firstName');
  let lname = formData.get('lastName');
  let gender = formData.get('gender');
  if (fname != "" || lname != "" || gender != "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPlayer',
        method: 'post',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
        success: (d) => {
          console.log("Player Added", d);
          players.innerHTML += d;
          form.reset();
        },
        error: (d) => {
            console.log("An error occurred. Please try again");
        }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```

Changes in **main.go**

```golang
Fname := r.FormValue("firstName")
Lname := r.FormValue("lastName")
Gender := r.FormValue("gender")

# return the last element added to slice before it was always returning the first element.
err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "displayPlayer", players[len(players) - 1])
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you! How would I remove the big gap between the buttons and the data passed back?

Comment: @JacobBrewer If you are asking about the api returning data its normal for apis to take some time to return data as there is processing involved to create the data and sending the data to client, which involve networking from server to client.

Comment: @JacobBrewer to show user data is being prepared and we will update the use as soon as processing is complete mostly loader/spinner are used.